# How to put List<webelement> into ArrayList using selenium web driver/java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a drop downlist, where i need to compare the new values with a old month string= Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells). Then if not equals then that is a new month and it should be downloaded, or else come out of the loop. Can I put the List into ArrayList and compare the string?

Please help

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
          //opening the PA page
          driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
        //maximizing the window
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));



          //List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

          String str="Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)";
```

Answer (score 1):

method below will pull out the current options of the dropdown to a List.

Best of Luck.

---

**Pull the current *'Reporting Period'* content to a List**

```
/**
 * Uses a {@link FirefoxDriver} to load the targeted website and extracts all current options of the 'Reporting
 * Period' drop down to a List of String references.
 * 
 * @return List of String references.
 */
private List<String> getCurrentReportingPeriodContent() {
    // List to hold the value we will return to the caller.
    List<String> currentOptions = new ArrayList<>();

    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    webDriver.get(
        "http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
    // maximizing the window
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();

    // This is the 'By.xpath' lookup used to find the dropdown field
    By reportingPeriodLookup = By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']");
    // Find the 'Reporting Period' drop down on the page.
    WebElement select = webDriver.findElement(reportingPeriodLookup); // Find the drop down

    // Pull out the options as web elements
    List<WebElement> matches = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    // Traverse the web elements to extrat the text. Text gets added to the 'currentOptions' List
    for (WebElement match : matches) {
        currentOptions.add(match.getText());
    }

    // Clean up the webdriver
    webDriver.close();

    // return the List of Strings pulled out of the 'options' back to the caller.
    return currentOptions;
}
```

Comment: you might be laughing now. Is this written in java? Please help me with java code

Comment: and I need only in webdriver :(

Comment: can we try this in webdriver please? you are of very much big help

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I've extracted the response to the approach I would suggest you apply.  You'll need to backfill your Driver setup, url, and xpath to the combo box.

Comment: I'm a very newbie, sorry can you help :( my deadline is tonight

Comment: I filled in your original url and the xpath for the dropdown.  If this needs further clarification please help me help you and provide specific line(s) that are giving you trouble.

Comment: can we do this in web driver please?

Comment: I feel like I've made the changes as straight-forward as I can without just writing it outright. I am willing to help you understand any portion of my proposal, but you need to ask more targeted questions about what is confusing to you. I'm willing to help, but I am not willing to do your work. I am certain that I am misinterpreting the intent of your question, so please provide more specific questions so I can help you.  Show me what you've done, tell me where it's going wrong, please provide more context to the help you're requesting.

Comment: May I know what is Logger here? I'm sorry if i am troubling you.

Comment: See if this works: 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
   WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
     List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
        //List <WebElement> Element1 = new ArrayList<WebElement>() ;for(WebElement option : options){
        if(option.getText().equals("Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)")) {System.out.println("No new month updated in the list");
                break;
                 }
           else { System.out.println("New month"); }

Comment: the above code only checking for only a particular string, but the requirement is it has to check if any new month is loaded into the drop down list and downloads that month too

Comment: The logger is an instance of  java.util.logging.Logger.  You can replace the logging statements with System.out.println() if you prefer.

Comment: What I think I'm understanding is that you want to know anything new that was added to the drop-down since the last time you ran your code.  Is that correct?

Comment: That changes the entire context of this question, doesn't it? If I were to do this I would look at it in chunks. What's the order of events that needs to happen for this to work. In my mind: 1) read state from filesystem (2) get current state from website (3) compare state to find 'new' content (4) write current state to file system (5) download 'new' entries.   I had been assuming the question was focused on step 2, but I'm getting the impression you want a bit more?  I'm updating my reply to assist with getting the current content into a list, but you may need additional posts for the rest.

Comment: if Sep is previous month and if it matches don't download, if not matches then that is a new month so we have to download it. Then again get txt of new month and overwrite it to txt file (so that this again becomes old month). This is how it has to work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98688/discussion-between-jeremiah-and-user2762008).

Comment: hi thr? may I know if you're available?

Comment: You're asking this same question all over.  You need to understand your work better. With the number of places that you're getting input from I don't feel like anything we've discussed has been helpful, and I don't feel like there is benefit to this conversation continuing.    You need to  ask better targeted questions to get help with the parts of the problem and put them together.  I don't feel like this site should be used to do your work for you, but rather to gain a better understanding of how to do the work.  That is my opinion, but for now I'm done helping with code.

Comment: If you want to discuss how to break down the work, and understand it, I will assist with that.  In concept only.  I will not be assisting with code until you understand your workflow and requirements.  I still wish you the best of luck if you choose not to follow up with me on that.

Comment: hi, sry for the delay

Comment: I worked on a code for a value to store in string, but somehow it is going wrong?